# Unable to display logged in user's id

Tags: php

I imneed to display logged in/authenticated user's id in html page. My sign in script is below followed by the display script. I've been on it for quite a while. I need to display logged in user's id from the mysql database to html.

```
       <?php
        session_start();
        include_once('server.php');

     $error = false;
      if(isset($_POST['btn-login'])){
       $username = trim($_POST['username']);
       $username = htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($username));

       $password = trim($_POST['password']);
       $password = htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($password));


     if(empty($username)){
    $error = true;
    $errorUsername = 'Please Input Username';
    }

     if(empty($password)){
    $error = true;
    $errorPassword = 'Please Input Password';       
    }elseif(strlen($password)< 6){
    $error = true;
    $errorPassword = 'Password must be at least six characters';
    }   

    if(!$error)
       {
    $password = md5($password);
    $sql = "select * from users where username = '$username'";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
    if($count==1 && $row['password'] == $password){
        $_SESSION['username'] = $row['username'];
        header('location: loggedin.php');
    }else{
        $errorMsg = 'Invalid Username or Password';
    }


    ?>

    //display script
    <?php
        session_start();
        echo 'welcome user'.$_SESSION['id'];
    ?>
```

Comment: Is that the complete code? Because I don't see any php tags around the first part nor is there a `session_start();` before you set the session value in your sign in code.

Comment: there's a display script underneath.

Comment: ok.. pls look at the script.

Comment: So, the only problem, which you have, is that the username is not displayed? Well, in the display script you call `$_SESSION['id']`, but that is never set. The only `$_SESSION` value, which you set is `$_SESSION['username']`. So, I assume, that is the problem.

Also, you should put an `exit;` behind your `header('Location: loggedin.php');`.

Comment: please how do I go about including session_id in log in script as you pointed out? No not the username... I achieved that. I need the id to be displayed.

Comment: If the ID is in the database, then you have to select it the same way you did for the username. Also, `session_id()` is the ID for the current session in php, not the user ID.
If you want to have the ID for the current session in php, then you could just put `$_SESSION['sessionid'] = session_id();`.

Comment: if you could give a demo or something, It would be lovely. Because I've tried but doesn't work.

Comment: So, which one do you want? The ID of the session in php or the an ID, which you take from the database?

Answer (score 2):

You need to set session like this.

`$_SESSION['id'] = row['id'];`

You are not getting the id value because $_SESSION['id'] is null.

Comment: This has already been written in the comments and it is only the answer, if he wants to display an ID, which is taken from the database. But reading the question and his comments, he has talked about "ID" from database and `session_id()`, which are two different things. So, first he needs to make clear, which one he wants/means.

Answer (score 0):

to display the loged user
change this:

```
echo 'welcome user'.$_SESSION['id'];
```

to this:

```
echo 'welcome user'.$_SESSION['username'];
```

because $_SESSION['id'] is not set and you most probably dont want to show it in the html page so just use the user name or set it to somthing more natural like actual name if it exists in your db row.

Comment: Your answer has already been written in the comments before. Also, the OP wrote in the comments, that he wanted to display the "id" and not "username".

Comment: Well, if the OP wants to show the id, then that is his decision.

Comment: Well, it's a suggestion, perhaps he would change his decision. Anyway I think he already knows but wants to know how,  but for any one reaching this site for help, this answer may help